# Select desired columns only on eager loading Many-to-Many relation typeorm

Tags: mysql, node.js, typeorm, eager-loading

I have 2 entities user and trip having many-to-many relationship with eager loading.
When I load trip I don't want all of user details to be return like I don't want the password or created and updated date etc just wanted name and id.

How can I do that?

Below are my two entities.

Trip entity

```
@Entity()
export class Trip {

  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @Index({ unique: true })
  name: string

  @ManyToOne(type => User)
  @JoinColumn()
  owner: User

  @Column()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  destination: string

  @ManyToMany(type => User, {
    eager: true
  })
  @JoinTable()
  buddies: User[]
}
```

User entity

```
@Entity()
export class User {

  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @Index({ unique: true })
  username: string

  @Column()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  firstName: string

  @Column({ default: null })
  lastName: string

  @Column({ unique: true, default: null })
  @Length(10, 12)
  phonenumber: string

  @Column()
  @Length(8, 16)
  password: string

  @Column()
  @CreateDateColumn()
  createdAt: Date;

  @Column()
  @UpdateDateColumn()
  updatedAt: Date;

  @BeforeUpdate()
  @BeforeInsert()
  hashPassword() {
    if (this.password) {
      this.password = bcrypt.hashSync(this.password, 8);
    }
  }

  checkIfUnencryptedPasswordIsValid(unencryptedPassword: string) {
    return bcrypt.compareSync(unencryptedPassword, this.password);
  }
}
```

Using it as

```
public doGetTripById = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    const tripId = req.params.tripId;

    const tripRepository = getRepository(Trip);
    let trip: Trip;

    try {
      trip = await tripRepository.findOneOrFail({ where: { id: tripId } });
      res.status(200).json(trip)
    } catch (error) {
      return res.status(400).json({ message: "Oops! somethig went haywire, possibly trip doesn't exist" })
    }
  }
```

I am able to get the required response with below changes but I am not satisfied with it.

```
trip.buddies.forEach(buddy => {
        buddy.password = undefined
        buddy.updatedAt = undefined
        buddy.createdAt = undefined
        buddy.phonenumber = undefined
      })
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this could solve the problem

You must create a QueryBuilder object and add the relation assigning an alias to the foreign table, then you can choose the columns you want.

```
tripRepository.createQueryBuilder("Trip")
  .innerJoinAndSelect("Trip.buddies", "Buddie")
  .select(["Trip.id", "Trip.name", "Buddie.firstName", "Buddie.lastName"])
  .where([...])
  .getMany()
```

regards,

Comment: Hi @cristroyer, the project is abandoned but thanks for the answer and I hope someone find it helpful  - Thank you.